# Extracting data from MS SQL server to CSV via batch file

Tags: sql-server, csv, batch-file

I need to write a batch file that will, among other things, connect to a MS SQL server and extract all the content of 3 tables (dbo.Group, dbo.Membership and dbo.Person) to 3 separate CSV files. The CSV files should be with headers (column names in the tables), semicolon separated and UTF-8.

The machine running the batch file will be Windows 10 or Server 2012, connecting to another server on the network running MS SQL Server.

Any ideas how to go about this?

Comment: Are you sure this needs to be fully contained in a batch file? You *do* have a SQL server...

Comment: Yes, unfortunately. It is all part of A Bigger Thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [sqlcmd Utility](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/sqlcmd-utility), for instance one command:

```
SQLCMD -S SERVER/INSTANCE -E -Q "SELECT * FROM Table1" -s ";" -o "C:\temp\file1.csv" -W
```

Comment: That did it! I ran the script as you wrote, added -u to get unicode and it works very well. Only question is that "(103 rows affected)" was added to the end of the CSV file. Is there any way to avoid this?

Comment: I think, adding "set nocount on" to the beginning of your query will solve this problem

Comment: this works well but for some reason the output has a second row with `----- , -----,`